# How to access attributes of an xml element which are keywords in ballerina?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, attributes, keyword, ballerina

Consider the below code segment written in ballerina.

```
xml xmlHello = xml `<para id="greeting">Hello</para>`;
string id = check xmlHello.id;
io:println(id);
```

In the above scenario, the output will be greeting.

Now consider the below.

```
xml xmlHello = xml `<para type="singlePara">Hello</para>`;
string paraType = check xmlHello.type;
io:println(paraType);
```

This gives an invalid token error since `type` is a keyword in Ballerina.  How to access the `type` attribute in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the single quote to escape the keywords.

```
string paraType = check xmlHello.'type;
```